# Mysql: How to use CASE in query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I have following query :

```
SELECT
    t.id as tid
  , t.uid tuid
  , t.bid_type
  , tt.type as type
  , t.bid_category
  , tc.type as category
  , t.name, if(t.description IS NULL
  , '-', t.description) as description
  , date_format(t.sdate, '%m-%d-%Y %H:%i') as tsdate
  , date_format(t.endate, '%m-%d-%Y %H:%i') as tendate
  , date_format(t.adate, '%m-%d-%Y %H:%i:%s') as tadate
  , if(t.edate IS NULL, '-', date_format(t.edate, '%m-%d-%Y %H:%i:%s')) as tedate
  , t.status
  , tq.id as tqid
  , tq.bid
  , if(tq.amount IS NULL, '-', tq.amount) as amount
  , if(tq.hand IS NULL, '-', tq.hand) as hand
  , if(tq.game = 0 OR tq.game IS NULL, '-', tg.type) as game
  , if(tq.stake = 0 OR tq.stake IS NULL, '-', ts.type) as stak
  , if(tq.player = 0 OR tq.player IS NULL, '-', tq.player) as player
  , if(tq.tourney IS NULL, '-', tq.tourney) as tourney
  , if(tq.propbet, 'Prop bet', '-') as propbet
  , if(tq.race, 'Race', '-') as race
  , tq.status as tqstatus 
  , CASE 
    WHEN tq.amount IS NOT NULL THEN tq.amount 
    WHEN tq.hand IS NOT NULL THEN tq.hand 
    WHEN tq.tourney IS NOT NULL THEN tq.tourney 
    WHEN tq.propbet IS NOT NULL THEN 'Prop bet' 
    WHEN tq.race IS NOT NULL THEN 'Race' 
    END CASE as bidData
FROM (bid t)
JOIN bid_quote tq ON tq.bid = t.id
JOIN bid_type tt ON tt.id = t.bid_type
                AND tt.pid = 0
JOIN bid_type tc ON tc.id = t.bid_category
JOIN bid_game tg ON tg.id = tq.game
JOIN bid_stake ts ON ts.id = tq.stake
```

Above mentioned query is giving errors. Can some one guide me how to rectify it so CASE should work in query.  Here's the error:

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE as bidData FROM (bid t) JOIN bid_quote tq ON tq.bid = t.id JOIN bid_' at line 9

Comment: Can you also paste the error message you are getting?

Comment: I think you should use nested IF. what if none of your statements are true?

Comment: Then the case will return NULL.

Comment: What do you want to have in bidData if all of the fields in the CASE are non-null? Say for instance that tq.amount IS NOT NULL and tq.hand is also NOT NULL. Should bidData contain the first one that is not null (in this example tq.amount)?

Comment: `SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE as bidData    FROM (bid t) JOIN bid_quote tq ON tq.bid = t.id JOIN bid_' at line 9` - That's why you must care to read error messages, they often tell you the exact problem.

Comment: it would help if you took the time to reformat your query in such a way that it's readable.

Answer (score 7):

Remove the word `CASE` in `END CASE`. In a query you end a case with `END` alone, in contrast to stored procedures.

PS: You know you're allowed to use enters and indentation in queries too, right? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There is case for Stored Procs and one for queries.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case

Comment: yes this is a source for much confusion. Bad documentation on MySQL's part not to cross-link the two pages.